# How to create an ActiveRecord model with some attributes that are stored in the database and some that are read from Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

In my application I have a user object model. I'm using koala and OmniAuth to access Facebook.

I'm trying to figure out how to add the data from Facebook to my model in such a way that my controller serializes it properly.

I already managed to get the data from Facebook in my controller like that:

```
token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]
api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
api.get_object("me")
```

And I think I figured up how to add an attribute to my Model without a DB column, but in a way that will keep it in the serialized response:

```
def fb_info
  {"fb_info" =>"should be here"}
end

def attributes
  super.merge('fb_info' => fb_info)
end
```

So what is the preferred way to put it all together? I need to somehow populate attributes in my model. In order to do that I need the access token in there. It seems messy to make calls from the controller to populate them, or to pass the token to the model. Is there a clean way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add setter method to your model, and perform all data transformations inside this method. In most cases, you can pass data to setter method from a controller exactly the same way as it can be done with any 'real' attribute. But to store this data into database you should handle it by yourself.

```
def virtual_column_name=(raw_data)
  # some code to handle raw_data and put it into database
end
```

Comment: It does seem straight forward and simple. The only problem I have with this approach is that in puts the controller in charge of populating the data in the model (also in a flow where the controller is supposed to read data). I'm not sure if this is best practice. In addition, when rendering a list of objects (for example) it forces to loop through all the model objects in the controller, which seems like too much model-related code in the controller.

Comment: Yes, controllers should be as simple as possible. If controller code is too complex, consider moving some parts of this code to model, or even to separate library. Sometimes `rails_best_practices` gem can give you a hint.